# Need to compare one value in AoH to another value in a second AoH

Tags: arrays, perl, nested-loops

Editing to be more clear:

I am going to be obtaining 2 queries from the database and storing them as AoH. The 2 queries are:

```
select
    ip_address, 
    testnet,
    t.email as email, 
    owner, 
    hr_manager_login as manager
from 
    lab_view 
    JOIN CMN_INT.AK_EMPLOYEE on owner = login 
    JOIN testnets t on t.name = testnet
where 
    DIVISION like 'TERM%' and TERM_DATE is not null
order by owner
```

and `select login from CMN_INT.AK_EMPLOYEE where DIVISION = q[Terminated Employees]`

For my original testing, I wasn't going to dive into the opening/using DBI, so I used dummy data. my $qr is an example of what I would get from the first query and my $qr2 is an example of what I would get from the second query. I want to see if the Manager value in the first AoH is found in the second (terminated employees) AoH. If it IS found, then the manager is a terminated employee and its name shouldn't be pushed to the %manager. I tried testing this out by inserting the below foreach code into my first foreach code, but it didn't work as the Manager Harry was still being pushed and printed.

```
foreach my $emp2 (@$qr2){
    if ($emp->{Manager} ne $emp2->{Login}){
        $manager{$emp->{Manager}} = 1; #capture all managers not also terminated related to $name. Done this way for when $name is undef
    }
}
```

I also tried to assign the $emp->{Manager} to a variable before the 2nd foreach and then use if ($M ne $emp2->{Login}), but that also didn't work.

Below is the first part of my testing code with dummy data for the queries I would run, minus all the elsifs :)

```
my $qr = [
    {IP=>'X.Y.Z.51',Testnet=>'bos-por-leg',Owner=>'Edmund', Email => 'bosemail', Manager => 'Tod'},
    {IP=>'X.Y.Z.52',Testnet=>'bos-por-2',Owner=>'Edmund', Email => 'boemail2',Manager => 'Tod'},
    {IP=>'X.Y.Z.53',Testnet=>'bos-por-leg',Owner=>'Edmund', Email => 'bosemail',Manager => 'Tod'},
    {IP=>'X.Y.Z.54',Testnet=>'sqa',Owner=>'Richard', Email => 'sqaemail',Manager => 'Harry'},
    {IP=>'X.Y.Z.55',Testnet=>'sqa',Owner=>'Richard', Email => 'sqaemail',Manager => 'Harry'},
    {IP=>'X.Y.Z.56',Testnet=>'fll-pro',Owner=>'Larry', Email => 'fllemail',Manager => 'Moe'},
    {IP=>'X.Y.Z.57',Testnet=>'fll-pro', Owner=>'', Email => 'fllemail',Manager => 'Tod'},
    {IP=>'X.Y.Z.58',Testnet=>'fll-pro2', Owner=>'', Email => 'flemail2', Manager => 'Curly'},
];
my $qr2 = [{Login => 'Tom'},
           {Login => 'Dick'},
           {Login => 'Harry'},
           ];
my $len = scalar @$qr;
my $l = $len;
my $a = @$qr[0]->{Owner};
func ($a);
my %ip;
my %test;
my $name;
my %manager;
my $ip_ref;
my $test_ref;
my $man_ref;
sub func{
    foreach my $emp (@$qr) {
        if ($l > 1 && $emp->{Owner} eq $a) {
            $name = $emp->{Owner} || 'Undefined'; #to use with email as $a will change as cycle thru
            $ip{$emp->{IP}} = $emp->{Testnet}; #capture all IPs related to owner $name
            $test{$emp->{Testnet}} = $emp->{Email}; #capture unique testnets only related to owner $name
            foreach my $emp2 (@$qr2){
                if ($emp->{Manager} ne $emp2->{Login}){
                $manager{$emp->{Manager}} = 1; #capture all managers not also term related to $name. Done this way for when $name is undef
                }
            }
            $l--; #to cycle thru array until reach last row
        }
    }
}
sub mail_func{
    my $n = shift;   #user 
    my $i = shift;   #ips
    my $t = shift;   #testnets
    my $m = shift;   #managers (multiple if owner is undef) --> to field
    print "User name is: $n\n";
    my @to_list;
        foreach my $value (values %{$t}){
            if ($value ne 'bosemail'){
                if (grep {$value} @to_list){next;}
                else {push(@to_list,$value . '@email.com');}
            }
        }
    foreach my $key (keys %{$m}){push(@to_list,$key . '@email.com');}
    print "@to_list\n";
    my @body;
    while ( my ( $key, $value ) = each %{$i} ) {
        my $b = "IP " . $key . " : Testnet " . $value . "\n";
        push (@body, $b);
    }
    print "@body\n";
}
```

In testing, I get:

```
User name is: Richard
sqaemail@email.com Harry@email.com   ##Harry shouldn't be added
IP X.Y.Z.54 : Testnet sqa
 IP X.Y.Z.55 : Testnet sqa
```

I appreciate all input on how to correct. If you need more code, please let me know. Also to note, the terminated employees list is pretty long, so I'm guessing I probably shouldn't even be comparing each value in one AoH to each value in another AoH via the loop method, but that is all I know :) I am trying to also see if there is a way to do what I want using only 1 query. Thank you.

Comment: You are testing whether the value of `$emp->{Manager}` (as string) is _equal_ to that of `$emp2->{Login}`.  Equal meaning down to spaces, newlines, and all. Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: @zdim if the 2 are equal, I don't want to push the Manager name because the Manager is terminated. If they are not equal, then I can push the Manager's name.

Comment: Fine ... but how  "_doesn't seem to work_"?  You don't say.

Comment: I was reminding you that `ne` means _not equal_, as it is common to see that people mean things to match but use `eq`.  I am looking at that since it is not at all clear what (else/other?) is not working in your code.  Also, what lists are you comparing, and what is that other "_terminated_" business?  I suggest you edit the post to clarify.

Comment: I did say, but perhaps not clearly enough. I wanted to see if the manager was also found to be in the terminated list. If he wasn't, then I could add him to %manager. If he was terminated, I didn't want to add him because emails couldn't be sent to him. I did this by trying to see if one value in the first AoH is found in the second AoH. So I did the foreach my $emp2 (@$qr2){...} inside my first AoH foreach my $emp (@$qr). I noted that in testing, Harry@email.com shows up when it shouldn't be added due to Harry also being a terminated employee.

Comment: That particular test is fine; perhaps the logic is off somewhere? For instance, you check `Harry` for _all_ `Login`s and it will be `ne` for both `Tom` and `Dick`. It all seems a little convoluted -- print debugging statements throughout to see what exactly the code is in fact doing.

Comment: @zdim I rearranged my paragraphs and added a bit more so hopefully the post is more clear now. I will try to add more debugging statements - I've done a number of them but perhaps I need to do one at each line :)

Comment: OK, thank you, it is _much_ clearer now. (The code is too convoluted, which is probably why you have errors -- but OK, that's your question.)  I'll look as time permits -- more importantly, hopefully it's clearer for other people :)  By debugging I meant for yourself (not in the post), then you'll likely figure it out.

Comment: When I run your code as it stands it prints nothing.  When I print the `%manager` the only one is `Tod` -- and this is because of `if ( ... && $emp->{Owner} eq $a)`, where `$a` is `Tod`.  There are number of corrections to be made but first: 1) the code doesn't do what you say 2) I don't see what you want with some conditions, like the one selecting `Tod`.  Please clean this up.

Comment: @zdim I didn't do the whole code with all of my elsifs, which is why you see Tod first. I did the printing after each line and I see where my error is. In comparing the manager to each name in the term list, I have it being added if it is different from at least one name instead of making sure it isn't in there at all :)

Comment: Good you got it figured out, and got an answer :).  A tip: Reduce code so that it does exhibit the error(s), so that people can copy-paste; that's an ideal. I did figure out the problem (was late to prepare for a post) but it's better if it is all ready for those who look at it.  Make it as clear and easy as you can for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I have missed something obvious, I think you're making things too complicated.

The following works for me.

**WARNING:** It uses the 'smartmatch operator' to search for an element within an array. AFAIK this feature is still deemed 'experimental'. Others might be able to comment on the status of that feature - or suggest a more suitable alternative.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $qr = [
    {IP=>'X.Y.Z.51',Testnet=>'bos-por-leg',Owner=>'Edmund', Email => 'bosemail', Manager => 'Tod'},
    {IP=>'X.Y.Z.52',Testnet=>'bos-por-2',Owner=>'Edmund', Email => 'boemail2',Manager => 'Tod'},
    {IP=>'X.Y.Z.53',Testnet=>'bos-por-leg',Owner=>'Edmund', Email => 'bosemail',Manager => 'Tod'},
    {IP=>'X.Y.Z.54',Testnet=>'sqa',Owner=>'Richard', Email => 'sqaemail',Manager => 'Harry'},
    {IP=>'X.Y.Z.55',Testnet=>'sqa',Owner=>'Richard', Email => 'sqaemail',Manager => 'Harry'},
    {IP=>'X.Y.Z.56',Testnet=>'fll-pro',Owner=>'Larry', Email => 'fllemail',Manager => 'Moe'},
    {IP=>'X.Y.Z.57',Testnet=>'fll-pro', Owner=>'', Email => 'fllemail',Manager => 'Tod'},
    {IP=>'X.Y.Z.58',Testnet=>'fll-pro2', Owner=>'', Email => 'flemail2', Manager => 'Curly'},
];

my $qr2 = [{Login => 'Tom'},
           {Login => 'Dick'},
           {Login => 'Harry'},
           ];

my @dismissed = map { $_->{Login} } @$qr2;

my @eligible = grep { !($_->{Manager} ~~ @dismissed) } @$qr;

say $_->{Testnet}, ', ', $_->{Email} foreach @eligible;
```

**Alternative DB queries**

Since you tagged the question with Perl rather than DBI, this is parenthetical - but I think is worth noting nonetheless.

You asked:

> I am trying to also see if there is a way to do what I want using only
>   1 query

I think there is - using the [NOT IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator. Something similar to the following will probably work - although you might need to alter the syntax slightly depending on the database server you are using.

Simple add another condition to your `WHERE` clause, so

```
where 
    DIVISION like 'TERM%' and TERM_DATE is not null
```

would become

```
where 
    DIVISION like 'TERM%' and TERM_DATE is not null
AND
    hr_manager_login NOT IN (select login from CMN_INT.AK_EMPLOYEE where DIVISION = q[Terminated Employees])
```

If the number of terminated employees is *extremely long* (you intimate it is 'quite long' - but don't specify exactly how long) there may be performance implications for using `NOT IN`, but I think that is probably not the case here.

Comment: You could just use a hash instead of `~~`: `my %dismissed = map { $_->{Login} => 1 } @$qr2; ... grep { !$dismissed{$_->{Manager}} } ...`

Comment: Thank you for answer. This wasn't quite what I needed as far as what I need to do overall. However, your my@dismissed was exactly what I needed instead of doing the second foreach, which I found out was the wrong logic thanks to zdim's debugging tip. I was then able to correctly do `my @term_emp = map {$_->{Login}} @$qr2;
            if (grep {$emp->{Manager} eq $_} @term_emp) {$manager{'jhaight'} = 1;}
            else {$manager{$emp->{Manager}} = 1;}` Therefore, I am marking it as the answer I needed.

Comment: As for "smart match," an easy advice is: don't.  It's clear that its workings will change so we better wait (than have broken code).  As for an alternative, see for example [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/List-MoreUtils-0.428/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm) (or just write a little more code)